# Trash bin problem

Tags: pantheon-files

Trash bin icon on the plank does not minimize the window. When I click on the Trash icon second time it opens another Trash window instead. How can I minimize it. Is there any solution or must wait for a OS update. Help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How did you get a trash icon on the Plank? That feature doesn't come with elementary as far as I'm aware.

Comment: You can put a Trash desklet to Plank (ctrl+click on _Plank_, _Preferences_, _Docklets_ tab)

Answer (score 1):

Actually if I understand correctly, you have the Trash docklet on your Plank. This is not the same as the other application icons on Plank. So actually the expected behavior is not to minimize on the second click, but to open.

If you can put a shortcut to your Trash to Plank (as a folder shortcut) it might work indeed as you expect it.